# Recovering files from a Windows account on an internal drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

I was wondering would there be problems if I tried to recover my files from my Windows 7 account on an internal drive that I took out of my laptop and then hooked up to my other laptop?

Will I have to input my Windows 7 password somewhere?

Is using a USB connector the best way to recover files from internal drive?

I would imagine you can't transfer data from a internal drive that had a password protect account without using a password!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a password if:

- the hard disk is not encrypted
- there are no files encrypted by the user

To connect the hard disk to your other laptop you can use:

- an SATA to USB adapter
- or if your notebook has an eSATA port you can connect the disk there with an eSATA to SATA cable

Note: The Windows password does not prevent the access to the data on the disc if you are able to physically access it. Booting with an other OS or connecting it to another computer is enough to gain access to all the files on the disc.